# Static Factory Method

Tags: java, static-methods

I learned that **static** methods are used to create an instance of a class type. I see that some classes using static method have to declare a **private constructor** for that class.

What is the use of private constructor? Can we still create an instance of a class without using the private constructor? Thanks.

Comment: google this - java private constructor

Comment: You can only create an instance of a class using a constructor. Marking the constructor as `private` simply prevents anyone else from using it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider we can still use/access a private constructor via reflection

Comment: @sol4me there's a difference between what one exposes as a `public` API and what can be dug out with reflection.

Comment: @BoristheSpider OP didn't mention how he want to create an instance all he mentioned is "Can we still create an instance of a class without using Private Constructor?"

Comment: Thank you all. @sol4me reflection sounds new to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we use this kind of static factory method in Singleton Design Pattern.

Singleton means based on this design pattern we can create only one object for the class.

for Example:

```
 class Test{
    private static Test mObject;
      private Test()
      {
      }
    public static Test getInstance(){
      if(mObject==null){
         mObject=new Test();
      } 
         return mObject;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I found this case in Singleton Design Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use of Private Constructor?

If a class has only private constructors and no public constructors, other classes (except nested classes) cannot create instances of this class

> Can we still create an instance of a class without using Private
>   Constructor

Yes using reflection (need to call [setAccessible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject[],%20boolean)) of [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html))